# שָׁמְרוּ and לַעֲשׂוֹת whats the diffrence

Tags: shabbat-songs

In the Song [וְשָׁמְרוּ](http://www.zemirotdatabase.org/view_song.php?id=199#rec) sung on Friday night by Chassidim

> וְשָׁמְרוּ בְנֵי יִשְֹרָאֵל אֶת־הַשַּׁבָּת, לַעֲשׂוֹת אֶת־הַשַּׁבָּת

Translated literally as: And you shall watch the Shabbos, make the Shabbos

What is the difference between the two parts of the statement it would seem that watching the Shabbos  and making the shabbos are two ways too say the same thing so why say both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is based on "shamor vezachor". Shamor relates to Mitzvot loh ta'aseh (things to avoid?) and Zachor relates to Mitzvot aseh (things we should do?).